# Magento2: How to fix this Sales order grid created_at filter ambiguous error?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

i needed custom column in **sales Order grid** so i applied joined on **sales order** with sales order grid but when I **filter** grid with **purchase date** It shows this error in logs and filter stop working.

```
Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `sales_order`.`coupon_code`, `sales_order_address`.`telephone`, `sales_order_address`.`city`, `sales_order_address`.`country_id` FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_order` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `sales_order_address` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order_address.parent_id WHERE  (((`created_at` >= '2023-02-15 19:00:00'))) AND (((`created_at` <= '2023-02-16 18:59:59'))) AND (sales_order_address.address_type =  'shipping') ORDER BY main_table.created_at DESC
 LIMIT 20 in /var/www/html/magento245/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:109
```

and my join is this.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'sales_order_grid',
        $resourceModel = Order::class
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }

    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        $this->addFilterToMap('created_at', 'main_table.created_at');
        parent::_initSelect();
    }

    public function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {

        $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order_address');
        $this->getSelect()
            ->join($joinTable, 'main_table.entity_id = sales_order_address.parent_id',array('telephone','city','country_id') )->where("sales_order_address.address_type =  'shipping'");

        $salesOrderTable = $this->getTable('sales_order');
        $this->getSelect()->join($salesOrderTable, 'main_table.entity_id = sales_order.entity_id',['coupon_code']);

        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }
}
```

**Any Idea what I'm missing?**

Answer (score 2):

What ever table you are joining if there is same field in both table.You can use your custom logic in this example as per your requriment.

```
    <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

/**
 * Class AddDataToOrdersGrid
 */
class AddDataToOrdersGrid
{
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * AddDataToOrdersGrid constructor.
     *
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $customLogger
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $customLogger,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->logger   = $customLogger;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection $collection
     * @param $requestName
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetReport($subject, $collection, $requestName)
    {
        if ($requestName !== 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
            return $collection;
        }

        if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_grid')) {
            try {
                $orderAddressTableName = $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_address');
                $directoryCountryRegionTableName = $collection->getResource()->getTable('directory_country_region');
                $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                    ['soa' => $orderAddressTableName],
                    'soa.parent_id = main_table.entity_id AND soa.address_type = \'shipping\'',
                    null
                );
                $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                    ['dcrt' => $directoryCountryRegionTableName],
                    'soa.region_id = dcrt.region_id',
                    ['code']
                );
            } catch (\Zend_Db_Select_Exception $selectException) {
                // Do nothing in that case
                $this->logger->log(100, $selectException);
            }
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this after plugin?

Comment: Yes it's after plugin.